# Sustainable solution using JMeter for a big functional flow

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

I have a huge flow to test using APIs. There are 3 endpoints. One is starting a process (db migration) that can last ~2-3 days, one is returning the status of the current running process (in progress, success, fail) and the last one is returning all the failed processes (as a list).

The whole flow should be:

1. Start the first process
2. Call the second endpoint until the first process ends (should get Fail or Success)
3. If the process failed, call the first endpoint again, if not, go to the next process.

   The problem is that 1 process can last around 2-3 days and we have around 20k processes to check. (this should take a lot of time). I do have a special VM only for this.

My question: does it worth trying to implement a solution for this using JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not worth implementing in JMeter unless you want to use the tool as a workload automation engine that replaces functionalities provided by UC4 AppWorkr or Control-M. Based on what you describe, it does not appear to be a load test except the 2nd part that continuously queries the services for success/failure. I do not know the architecture behind that implementation. Hence, I am unable to quantify even that would be a load test or not.

Comment: Behind "the scene" are some websockets listening to all requests received from user. First call trigger a database backup. I left this information here in case someone find this useful. Thank you